# Android Ble Write

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Strange Scenario Happen for Same Code Written for Android 4.4.2 OS Samsung  and Samsung (A8) Android 5.1.1 .

```
if(mBluetoothGattCharacteristic==null){
            return;
        }

        byte [] mCommandData=new byte[64];
        mCommandData[0]=Constants.REMOTE_CMD;
        mCommandData[1]=(byte) mRemoteCommand;

        mBluetoothGattCharacteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE);

        boolean isUpdated= mBluetoothGattCharacteristic.setValue(mCommandData);
        boolean isWriteDone=mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(mBluetoothGattCharacteristic);
        LogUtils.i("LOG", "Ble Write set is---"+  isUpdated + " Characteristics Write done"+ isWriteDone);

        /**
         * Create New Command Release Key
         */

        byte [] mCommandRelease=new byte[64];

        mCommandRelease[0]=Constants.REMOTE_CMD;
        mCommandData[1]=(byte)Constants.IR_KEY_RELEASE;

        isUpdated= mBluetoothGattCharacteristic.setValue(mCommandData);
        isWriteDone=mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(mBluetoothGattCharacteristic);
        LogUtils.i("LOG", "Ble Write set is---"+  isUpdated + " Characteristics Write done"+ isWriteDone);
```

In Above code for android 4.4.2 `writeCharacteristic` give true for both command write .

But in case of android 5.1.1 it give true for first time write and when it's continue to write next it give false in `writeCharacteristic`

Now solution i am thinking is in android 5.1.1 i have to wait for `onCharacteristicWrite` and then write next command .

Guide me if any one known such issue and does this happen to Samsung device only ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For now i sort out issue by putting my next command in `onCharacteristicWrite`,

I found that we should not write code like this :

```
BluetoothGattCharacteristic.setValue(mCommandData);
boolean isWriteDone=mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(mBluetoothGattCharacteristic);
```

then again send next command :

```
BluetoothGattCharacteristic.setValue(mNextCommdn);
boolean isWriteDone=mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(mBluetoothGattCharacteristic);
```

So we try to perform two write operation on GATT profile then only first one may execute successfully .

So i write my next command base on result receive of first command :
which will be receive in  `onCharacteristicWrite`.

Comment: This is the correct solution. There can only be one outstanding GATT operation at a time in Android's BLE API.